# Data loss in iteration of slice of pointers

Tags: go

On iterating over a slice of pointer to struct, I observed that slice is losing some elements at the end of the iteration. In this iteration I am not even modifying the struct. Just generating a modified value(preparedExpr) from ELGExpr and doing this operation

```
        map[x.Id] = &commons.Y{
            PreparedEligibilityExpr: &preparedExpr,
            X:         x,
        }.
```

One peculiar observation is it loses elements which has empty CId. Can someone here please help me ?

For reference the struct that I am iterating over

```
type X struct 
{
Id                       string           
CId                      string           
ElGExpr                 []*ASTNode       
Meta                    *pMeta 
RateLimit               *RateLimit      
CRateLimit              *RateLimit      `
}
```

**Iteration Code**

```
    sl = []*X          // just for understanding, in my code function 
                      //  takes sl as input param
    res := map[string]*commons.PreparedExpressionData{}
    for _, x := range sl {
        protoAstNodes := x.ElGExpr
        unmarshalledNodes := commons.UnmarshalProtoToASTNodes(protoAstNodes)
        astTree, err := commons.Decode(astNodes)
        if err != nil {
            log.Error().Msg("error in preparing eligibility expr")
            continue
        }
        preparedExpr := commons.PreparedExpr{Value: astTree}
        res[x.Id]] = &commons.PreparedExpressionData{
            PreparedEligibilityExpr: &preparedExpr,
            X:         x,
        }
    }
```

Comment: Would you be able to share more of the iteration code?

Comment: Id is unique. Using a uuid here.

Answer (score 0):

It was getting modified by another routine processing in parallel which was sorting the slice